# How to calculate number of digits after floating point in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

How can I calculate the number of digits after the floating point in iOS?

For example:

- 3.105 should return 3
- 3.0 should return 0
- 2.2 should return 1

**Update:**
Also we need to add the following example. As I want to know number of digits in the fraction part.

- 1e-1 should return 1

Comment: cast into NSString, then find dot position?

Comment: @iiFreeman just be aware that not all locales uses dot for their decimal point

Comment: It is not possible to have 3.105 or 2.2 as a `float` or `double` value in iOS (with the standard Apple tools), because these values are not representable in binary floating-point. Do you have the values in another format? If not, are you passing numbers near these values, e.g., 2.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125 instead of 2.2? Then what criteria should be used to determine whether to treat this as 2.2 rather than 2.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I used is the following:

```
NSString *priorityString = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.priority] stringValue];
    NSRange range = [priorityString rangeOfString:@"."];
    int digits;
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        priorityString = [priorityString substringFromIndex:range.location + 1];
        digits = [priorityString length];
    } else {
        range = [priorityString rangeOfString:@"e-"];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            priorityString = [priorityString substringFromIndex:range.location + 2];
            digits = [priorityString intValue];
        } else {
            digits = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this way:

```
NSString *enteredValue=@"99.1234";

NSArray *array=[enteredValue componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSLog(@"->Count : %ld",[array[1] length]);
```

Comment: You will need to trim 0s off the end first. A float always displays 8 (IIRC) decimal digits. i.e. 3.00000000 would return 8 I think? And as David commented, you'll have to find the correct separator for decimal based on the locale.

Comment: @Fogmeister: You are right, I solved as per the examples in question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more elegant way to do this, but when converting from a 32 bit architecture app to a 64 bit architecture, many of the other ways I found lost precision and messed things up. So here's how I do it:

```
bool didHitDot = false;    
int numDecimals = 0;
NSString *doubleAsString = [doubleNumber stringValue];

for (NSInteger charIdx=0; charIdx < doubleAsString.length; charIdx++){

    if ([doubleAsString characterAtIndex:charIdx] == '.'){
        didHitDot = true;
    }

    if (didHitDot){
        numDecimals++;
    }
}

//numDecimals now has the right value
```